# use edit distance on arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I am attempting to compare the edit distance between two arrays. I have tried using Text:Levenshtein.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);

my @words = qw(four foo bar);
my @list = qw(foo fear);
my @distances = distance(@list, @words);

print "@distances\n";
#results: 3 2 0 3
```

I however want the results to appear as follows:

```
2 0 3
2 3 2
```

Taking the first element of @list through the array of @words and doing the same through out the rest of the elements of @list.
I plan on upscaling this to a much larger arrays.

Comment: In your example, `distance(@list, @words)` is equivalent to `distance('foo', 'fear', 'four', 'foo', 'bar')`, which computes the edit distance between "foo" and "fear", "foo" and "four", "foo" and "foo", and "foo" and "bar".

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you meant, but I think this is what you expect :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);

my @words = qw(four foo bar);
my @list = qw(foo fear);

foreach my $word (@list) {
   my @distances = distance($word, @words);
   print "@distances\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

> Taking the first element of `@list` through the array of `@words` and doing the same through out the rest of the elements of `@list`.

You just described exactly what you need to do to get the output you would like; loop through the `@list` array and for each element compute the distance for all elements of the `@words` array.